# Create custom macro for C++ configuration in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, macros

Background:

I found some answers for this question but they were focused more on earlier versions of visual studio for which it seems some things have changed. My issue is I've created a new build configuration called 'Profile' for which I would like to have a corresponding macro for similar to how visual studio's 'Debug' build has '_DEBUG' macro.

Question:

Where, in visual studio 2015, would I go about declaring a macro connected to my build configuration so I can use #if, #ifelse and other defines with the macro in my code? This relates to C++.

Comment: [Same place as in previous versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx): Project > Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor >  Preprocessor Definitions. Pay attention to Active Configuration drop-down at the top left.

Comment: Well I know I can define preprocessor macro's there but how would I define a macro that can represent my 'Profile' configuration option like with debug? For example, in my code I can do   '#if (_DEBUG) ..do something'    So any code immediately following the #if (_DEBUG) will run automatically when I select the debug configuration option.

Comment: Add `_PROFILE=1` in `Preprocessor Definitions` for Profile configuration only. Now you can write `#if _PROFILE` / `#endif` around code that should only be compiled in Profile configuration.